# Should i split my async calls into chunks according to the number of CPUs?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

Consider this script on a 8 processor machine:

```
int parallel_function(int i){
    system(some_complex_and_long_call);
    return i;
}

int main() {
    // Parallel run
    std::vector<std::future<int>> futures;
    for(int i = 30; i > 0; i--) {
        futures.push_back (std::async(std::launch::async, parallel_function, i));
    }
    std::cout << "Stuff submitted" << std::endl;
    for(auto &e : futures) {
        std::cout << e.get() << std::endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

It will spawn 30 system calls in async, however i only have 8 processors, and each system call can (and i guess should) use 100% of a single processor.

Is it better to run only 8 call at a time (or even 7, and leave on processor free) or it does not matter, and i can call as many as i want. Which will run faster and why?

Another side question:
Can i call a `void` function in async, or the function must return something?

Comment: Probably. Maybe. Depends on a lot of stuff. Why not just try it and see? It's the only way to be sure anyway, whatever the internet tells you.

Comment: @Useless Sure i can try, the problem is that my system call takes like a month to run (they are expensive simulations) so i though ask first may be better :)

Comment: @GáborErdős it doesn't have to finish for you to tell if it's consuming all of the CPU resources.

Comment: @xaxxon I dont really follow. As i wrote even 1 call makes the CPU to 100%. So as 30 calls.

Comment: @GáborErdős you didn't say that.  You said "can" and "should" but not "does".

Comment: @xaxxon The system call i very complex, and by "it can" i ment that there are times when the CPU is on 100%.

Comment: @GáborErdős well, depending on how often it's at 100% will determine whether you should schedule more.   Maybe try to make simpler simulations for testing.. or have some sort of partial progress report so you can get a sense of how much work is being done and then try different number of threads/processes/whatever to see if it's better/worse.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, If the system calls (processes) run continuously on the cpu then with 8 threads you will get max performance. Although if your calls have chunks of time sleeping, waiting other stuff then you can create more threads to run in parallel. Either way i barely doubt that you will see performance gain if you spawn just 8 in turns and not all 30 because you os will do some scheduling, probably a little bit better than your scheduling, most of the times.

Comment: @k_kaz Thanks, if you put that in an answer i will gladly up it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the implementation of `std:async`.

If `some_complex_and_long_call` is indeed CPU bound task, then having the number of threads as the number of your (logical) cores seems reasonable.

GCC actually spawns a thread for each `std::async` call, so you might not want to use GCC version of `async` too much. thread creation, scheduling and destruction is expensive, and context switches will kill your performance. in this case, I suggest you find a thread-pool implementation (there are plenty on github) and use a threadpool instead of `async`.

Both Clang and VC++ uses a threadpool behind the scenes when calling `std::async` so if you are using these compilers, spawn as many `async` as you want and the underlying implementation will take care of thread creation for you.

> Another side question: Can i call a void function in async, or the
>   function must return something?

yes, it is possible. in this case `std::async` will return `std::future<void>`.

Answer (score 1):

*In general* 1 thread per physical core is probably best, *if* the threads are CPU-bound, and *in principle* one task per thread minimises time spent managing tasks rather than doing actual work.

This assumes your tasks (async `parallel_function` calls) all take about the same time to complete. If that's not the case, you need more tasks to keep the first-finishing core(s) busy.

If it takes a month to run (which is relevant information that should be in the question), I doubt that 24 avoidable synchronisation ops make a whole lot of difference.

If your scheduler does lots more context-switching than that, it really might slow everything down, but I don't know your platform or whether that's the case.

---

See all the *ifs* and handwaving above? They translate to:

**tl;dr** *Probably. Maybe. Depends on a lot of stuff. Why not just try it and see? It's the only way to be sure anyway, whatever the internet tells you.*